# Windows Explorer hangs, while "working on it" (Quick Access)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze

Have this situation where Windows Explorer hangs indefinitely every time I open it (Windows 10).

But when you open Explorer for a specific folder (for instance by entering `C:\` in the start menu search box) it opens and runs just fine. And without any delay.

Everything is alright until you accidentally click on "Quick Access", then it also freezes.

So it appears that it wants to show the "Quick Access" items by default.
Quick Access appears to be the modern variant of the recently opened files list.

Workaround:

Elsewhere on the web I learned that if you have a chance to run explorer normally, you can temporarily fix the situation.

If you have it running normally:

1. right click on the top left "Quick Access" tree node in the navigation pane
2. choose "Options" from the popup menu
3. find the "Privacy" group box in the dialog
4. press the "Clear" button.

This makes the quick access screen forget about all the files - which possibly includes missing, broken or just very large files.

So the bottom line is that there is a problem with this "Quick Access" frame, but how to debug something like this?
Tried debugging with Visual Studio but then it only shows that the project is blocking on one of the win32 wait functions.

Comment: Does your quick access list include any unmapped network/UNC paths? Or a OneDrive account?

Comment: Yes. it probably contains a broken link or something like that. But how do you figure that out other than guessing. Meanwhile I've restored explorer to a working state, but it still bothers me I can't debug it myself.